# How do I add jQuery to specific node form?

Tags: javascript, theming

I'm using an Omega sub-theme and I want to do this the correct (best practice) way.

Basically I'd like to add some script so that selects a value in a select box based on a previously selected value in another select box. I have the code, just need to plug it in to my theme now.

However, I only want it to load on node creation forms of node type "X".

Any help greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Install the [JS injector](http://drupal.org/project/js_injector) module. Then go to *admin/config/development/js-injector*. Add a new rule. Fill the *JS code* field with your script.

In the *Pages* fieldset select the *Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)* option and enter the following code:

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'add' && arg(2) == 'content_type') {
 return true;
}
return false;
?>
```

Replace `content_type` with your content type name.

This is a theme independent solution. Another way is adding your script in `hook_preprocess_page` in *template.php* file of your theme.

Comment: Great, thank you. I'm using v2.0 of the js-Injector module and I have no option to select PHP input on the pages fieldset. I've put it in anyway to try it out but my directory permissions are not configured correctly, do you have any idea which permissions I need to set and where?

Comment: @jonthomas83 First enable the PHP filter module.

Comment: Thanks, PHP Filter enabled, but still no "select the Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE", also I have an error saying "The specified file temporary://fileZXBaLq could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions." Any ideas which permissions I need to set and where?

Answer (score 1):

Have you take a look to drupal native [ajax](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax)?

If ahah is not good for you, you should add the jquery in the #after_build function, because when a validation go wrong, Drupal no add all the js files. With after_build function it will always add your js (http://drupal.org/node/322290#comment-1189081)

I hope this help you.

Oskar